# db insert returning gibberish values with numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Assuming this is a host issue, but I don't see how it could be reading wrong (works perfectly on locahost)

I an returning an `array` called `$result`, for this instance of the loop, `$v` is a telephone number

`$k = 'phone';`
`$v = '(555) 555-1212)';`

I have tried

```
$result[$k] = preg_replace('/(\W*)/', '', $v);
```

I have also tried

```
$result[$k] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $v);
```

I have received values for `$v` of anything from `-198040413` to `1260583916`
expected result would be `5555551212`

echoing results to page for both cases gives expected result, so its not a preg_repalce issue, must be db issue

I know this is not an `int` limit issue, I am using a `varchar(10)` for testing the problem

host is `Arvixe.com` using `PHP 5.3.27`, I have had other conflicts with them, but `preg_replace` should be pretty straight forward code (you would think)

Comment: Try to check `echo preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $v);` first.

Comment: You need to reduce the scope of the problem. Try to echo it first without saving it to the database. If it doesn't work as expected you could safely say that the database is ok and that the problem is somewhere else. Now, I can't really see what's the problem. You didn't give the expected results and what you actually are getting. Also the thing about `int`: `preg_replace()` doesn't return an int, it returns a string. Basically I think you're mixing up things

Comment: updated with expected result, 10 digit number only

Comment: @Kender the result is the same in [100 different PHP](http://3v4l.org/IieRK) versions. As it stands now, your question is "offtopic" as it can't be reproduced ...

Comment: @Kender how are you inserting them ? Also what's the encoding of your column ? It might be an encoding issue ...

Comment: resolution below, thanks @HamZa for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, it was with the insert

I was inserting into a `varchar` using `i` as type, changing it to `s` as type fixed it

```
// does not work
bind_param('i', $phone);

// does work
bind_param('s', $phone);
```

when inserting into a `varchar` field

Comment: Great. Remember i is used when the corresponding variable has type integer and s is used when the corresponding variable has type string. For more information, go to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: my only question is...  why would a `varchar` insert alter the input data even if it is a totally numeric value? would the solution been as easy as wrapping the insert in quotes?